# What would be the EAFP way when the source of an Exception is not known?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and trying to understand the Python way®
I get the **EAFP** principle and I like it, but **how would it be applied** in this example?

**edit:** I only care about *item* not having a *children* property, not about what happens inside dosomethingwith().
In my understanding of EAFP, I should use the possibly erroneous statement as usually, and catch the exception, but as the statement is in a *for*, then I'm forced to try the whole for block.

```
try:
    for child in item.children:
        dosomethingwith( child )
except AttributeError:
    """ did the exception come from item.children or from dosomethingwith()? """
```

Doing something like this, though, looks a lot like LBYL:

```
try:
    item.children
except AttributeError:
    """ catch it """
for child in item.children: ...
```

Comment: You put the `try` inside the `for` loop, not encapsulate the whole loop

Comment: EAFP: It is easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission.

Comment: @roganjosh I edited the question to make clear I wanted to try & catch only the for expression, not the whole block

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Right, but is there a way to not ask for permission here? trying for item.children before actually using it looks more like asking for permission than asking for forgiveness in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you use EAFP when you want to access a resource which may not be available. IMO, `AttributeError` is a bad example…

Anyway, you can make the difference between the missing `children` attribute and an `AttributeError` raised from the `do_something_with()` function. You need to have two exception handlers:

```py
try:
    children = item.children
except AttributeError:
    print("Missing 'children' attribute")
    raise  # re-raise
else:
    for child in children:
        try:
            do_something_with(child)
        except AttributeError:
            print("raised from do_something_with()")
            raise  # re-raise
```

A classic example of EAFP is the `make_dir_if_not_exist()` function:

```py
# LBYL 
if not os.path.exists("folder"):
    os.mkdir("folder")

# EAFP 
try:
    os.mkdir("folder")
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, what I didn't specify is that the only AttributeError I cared for was for item.children, so basically my second example is almost the same as your answer, only it looks kind of LBYL to me.